# Most powerful test for BETA(a,b)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

A single observation $X$ is taken from a $BETA(a, b)$ distribution.

Given the hypothesis

$$ H_0 : a=b=1 \space vs\space H_1 : a=b=\frac{1}{2} $$

I want to find the Most Powerful test.

Well, we know by the Neyman-Pearson lemma that:
$$  \frac{f(\widetilde{x}/\theta_1)}{f(\widetilde{x}/\theta_0)}  > k $$ to some $$ k > 0 $$ we will have a UMP with size $$ \alpha=0.05 $$ such that $$ P(X \space \epsilon \space R | \theta = \theta_0) = \alpha  $$

Then,

$$  \frac{f(\widetilde{x}/\theta_1)}{f(\widetilde{x}/\theta_0)}= \frac{1}{\pi} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} (1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  > k$$

If I were to graph that I would get a global minimum at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and that the support $x \in [0,1]$ but I am not sure where to go from here. Just to mention that is a self-study thing! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry tells us our rejection region is of the form $$ |x-\frac{1}{2}|> f(k).$$ (If you do the algebra, it is $f(k)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi^2 k^2}}$.) So it's the region outside of some interval centered inside $(0,1)$.

Since our null hypothesis is a uniform distribution, we don't even need to go through anything more than mental math: this immediately means that for $\alpha=0.05$ we reject if $0<x<0.025$ or if $.975<x<1.$

If you want to get a $k$, you just solve for $f(k) = 0.475,$ but it seems almost counterproductive to do so. You might want to compute the power by integrating the $beta(1/2,1/2)$ distribution over the rejection region.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Would you mind elaborating on how you arrive at $$f(k)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi^2 k^2}}$$ ( you mentioned, I have to do some algebra). Though I am aware of where the $f(k)=\frac{19}{40}=0.475$ come from.

Comment: @ADAM Solve $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}} = k\pi$ for $x.$ You get $$ x = \frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{\pi^2k^2}}$$